# Is the category of enriched operads (co)complete?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, operads, enriched-category-theory

Let $V$ be a symmetric monoidal category
which is complete and cocomplete.
Is the category of small symmetric colored $V$-enriched operads complete and cocomplete?
If $V$ is presentable,
is it presentable?

#### Background

In the case of $V$-enriched categories,
corresponding results are proven in the following papers:

- Wolff, *$V$-cat and $V$-graph*.
- Kelly, Lack, *$V$-Cat is locally presentable or locally bounded if $V$ is so*.

Comment: In the case that $V$ is co-complete then the category of $V$-enriched symmetric multicategories (aka symmetric colored operads) is co-complete. This is discussed here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4146, but it really is a straightforward generalization of the statements in the paper by Elmendorff and Mandell cited in that paper.

Comment: @JonathanBeardsley Thank you. I found [Robertson] just said that the result was shown in [EM]. Could you tell me which part of [EM] she cited?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to both questions is yes. It's a special case of the fact that, for any colored operad $P$, the category of $P$-algebras is bicomplete (when $V$ is) and is presentable (when $V$ is). For the former statement, you can check out Schwede-Shipley's "[Algebras and modules in monoidal model categories](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/AlgebrasModules.pdf)", where this is handled in the case of a monad with a condition on the forgetful functor (one that's always satisfied for algebras over a colored operad). For the second statement, I learned this from Lurie's book "Higher Algebra". He discusses it for commutative monoids, and I believe he generalizes that later for other operads. If not, the generalization would be easy.

The above is if you have fixed a color set. If you haven't, then the relevant papers to check out are "[A Model Structure for Enriched Coloured Operads](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6983)" by Caviglia, and " [Dwyer-Kan Homotopy Theory of Algebras over Operadic Collections](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.01867)" by Yau.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any result on presentability when color sets are not fixed?

Comment: Yes, it's Theorem 4.2.5 in the paper by Yau that I cited above. The version for $\infty$-operads is 2.1.4 of Lurie's higher algebra

Comment: 4.2.5 in [Yau] seems to be a theorem for enriched categories.

Comment: The main result of [Yau] (6.5.5) includes the operad case, but I cannot find whether his ``Dwyer-Kan model structure'' is combinatorial.